# Failed to start NPM when published to IIS

Tags: angular7, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm publishing my asp.net core 2.2 Angular 7 web application to IIS and I get below errors:

1. Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
2. InvalidOperationException: Failed to start 'npm'.
3. AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start 'npm'. To resolve this:. [1] Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories).

This is for a Asp.Net core web application on Windows 2012 R2 server running IIS 8.
My local machine with IIS 8 has same errors.

---

My launchsettings.json profile:

```
   "Test.IIS": {
        "commandName": "IIS",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
   },
   "ancmHostingModel": "InProcess",
   "applicationUrl": "ttps://localhost:5002"
   }
```

---

Below is my startup.cs file:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //To check which process is runing the application
        //app.Run(async (contenxt) => {
        //    await contenxt.Response.WriteAsync(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
        //});

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

The code compiles successfully but throws the errors in run time.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a known issue in asp.net core 2.2 if you've adopted the IIS in-process hosting model.

The issue has been documented here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5263 which links to another github issue here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4206

While a patch is developed, the workaround is to add the following helper (change the namespace as required):

```
using System;

namespace SampleApp
{
    internal class CurrentDirectoryHelpers
    {
        internal const string AspNetCoreModuleDll = "aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll";

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(AspNetCoreModuleDll)]
        private static extern int http_get_application_properties(ref IISConfigurationData iiConfigData);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct IISConfigurationData
        {
            public IntPtr pNativeApplication;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            public string pwzFullApplicationPath;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            public string pwzVirtualApplicationPath;
            public bool fWindowsAuthEnabled;
            public bool fBasicAuthEnabled;
            public bool fAnonymousAuthEnable;
        }

        public static void SetCurrentDirectory()
        {
            try
            {
                // Check if physical path was provided by ANCM
                var sitePhysicalPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_IIS_PHYSICAL_PATH");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sitePhysicalPath))
                {
                    // Skip if not running ANCM InProcess
                    if (GetModuleHandle(AspNetCoreModuleDll) == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    IISConfigurationData configurationData = default(IISConfigurationData);
                    if (http_get_application_properties(ref configurationData) != 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    sitePhysicalPath = configurationData.pwzFullApplicationPath;
                }

                Environment.CurrentDirectory = sitePhysicalPath;
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then the following code to the first line of your Program.cs file:

```
CurrentDirectoryHelpers.SetCurrentDirectory();
```

I ran into the same problem and this work around solved it for me.

Comment: Thank you Kenspeckle! Will try this solution and update you.